# Trying to Mock a Service in angular for test cases, but still getting "No Provider for HTTPClient"

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine, case

I am trying to run test cases for a project in Angular in my Home Component. The component uses an ApiCallService, and I am trying to mock it for the tests. However, I keep getting the same error thrown. The 'create' test case runs, but the test case to see if 'Test' is written on the page gives the 'No Provider for HTTPClient' error. HttpClient and HttpClientModule is imported in app.module.ts as well.

```js
    import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
    import { ApiCallService } from 'src/app/core/service/api-call.service';
    
    describe('HomeComponent', () => {
      let component: HomeComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
      let service: ApiCallService;
      let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
      let httpClient: HttpClient;
    
     
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [ApiCallService, HomeComponent]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(ApiCallService);
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(ApiCallService).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
    
    
    
    it('TEST123', () => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      expect(compiled.querySelector('p')?.textContent).toContain('Test');
    });
```

Comment: Why is `HomeComponent` in your `providers` array?

Comment: You're also not mocking the service here. If you're just unit testing `HomeComponent`, you don't need `HttpClient` if it's only a dependency of the service.

Comment: declarations: [ HomeComponent ] bro, providers only for services

Comment: Sorry, my mentor had mentioned this was the way to go. I am new to unit testing and am an intern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **unit testing** the HomeComponent, you are doing it wrong.
What you should do is:

- Remove the HomeComponent from the TestBed 'providers' and add it under 'declarations'
- If the HomeComponent is not using directly (injecting in the constructor) the HttpClient service, there is no need to use HttpClientTestingModule, instead, you have to create a spy to mock ApiCallService like described in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed).
- If the HomeComponent is using directly the HttpClient service you will be obliged to test HTTP requests. Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests). And you still have to mock ApiCallService.

Comment: This is true if OP is unit testing, less so if they're integration testing.